# Highcharts: moving yAxes from left to right

Tags: highcharts

I'm writing a Highchart based widget where user can add/remove yAxes and bind series to them.
And I need to find a way to move yAxis from right to left (change opposite to false) together with all series bounded to that axis. So the scenario is the following:
1)   User adds series to left yAxis
2)   User adds series to right yAxis
3)   User removes left yAxis with all it's series
4)   Right yAxis must move to the left side

I'm stuck on the last action. Just switching "opposite" to false and redrawing a chart doesn't change anything. I've tried copying series object with jQuert.extend(), but after adding to chart I get "Out of stack space" error.

Please help me find a way to deal with this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `chart.yAxis[index].update( { opposite: false });` - only usable with Highcharts 3.0+

Comment: That works like a charm! Thank you for quick and exceptionally helpful reply!